# Extract Counter information from a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
myDict.items()

('RI.16498.172.249.dcm',
  '~/pythonTests/20130206162339/1CW/20-03-13'),
('RI.134.45.dcm',
  '~/pythonTests/20130206162339/2CCW/18-02-13'),
 ('RI.16671.160.134.dcm',
  '~/pythonTests/20130206162339/1CW/20-02-13')]
.....
```

which indicates files and their location. There are files who share the location and I need to be able to extract that information. For instance, I would like to know how many files belong to `"1CW"` on the date `"20-03-13"` (see first element of my dictionary)

I have tried with `Counter`:

```
 counts = Counter((k[1], v) for k, v in myDict.items())
 counts
 Counter({('I', '~/pythonTests/20130206162339/1CW/20-02-13'): 47, ('I', '~/pythonTests/1.2.246.352.71.5.22453062.437221.20130206162339/1CW/18-02-13'): 52, ......
```

but I still cannot see the way I could query for the information I want. Any idea of how I could do that?

My aim is to obtain the number of occurrences given a date (20-03-13) and a field (1CW or 2CCW):

```
Num = getValues("1CW","20-03-13")
```

Comment: Could you explain what is exactly your aim? What is the exact information you need to extract?

Comment: You could also use regex to search for a pattern in your dict-values. Or you could use re.split("/", [value]) which makes a list like [~, pythonTests, 20130206162339, 1CW, 20-03-13]

Comment: Are you using python2.7 and python3.4 at the same time? No? Then don't tag a question with both versions. I've removed both tags as they should only be used if your question is version-specific, which this one is not.

Comment: @Manolete, see my edit in order to achieve your goal (and mark it as correct if you think it is correct ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to just obtain the number of times each path appears, then you must do

```
counts = Counter(v for k, v in myDict.items())
```

As you can see here, you are not using the 'for' command properly; When you use 'for' to iterate over the items on a dictionary, the first variable (in this case 'k') corresponds to the keys in the dictionary (in your example the name of the file) while the second variable ('v') corresponds to the value (the path of the file). In your code, you were doing k[1] which is not what you were looking for  as that will just take the second character on the file name, taking k as an array of character, and that´s why you are getting this strange 'I' character on the Counter object.

By changing the result of the for loop to just the value ('v') you will initialize the Counter to act over the paths instead of over the names.

EDIT:As you say your aim is to have a function that depends on both date and prefix, I propose you the following solution :

```
def compute(dict, prefix, date):
    counts = Counter((v.split('/')[3], v.split('/')[4]) for v in dict.values()])
    return counts.get((prefix, date))
```

Please pay attention on the parenthesis around the tuple; If you don't put them, the constructor of `Counter` will think these are two different parameters instead of a tuple.

After that, you just need to call the function with the corresponding parameters:

```
res = compute(myDict, "1CW", "20-03-13")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [i.split('/') for i in d.itervalues()]
c = [i.count('1CW') for i in a if i[4] == '20-02-12']
```

this is will do what actually you are wishing.

```
s = []
    for i in d.itervalues():
        s.append(i.split('/'))
    print s
    for i in s:
        if i[4] == '20-02-13':
            print i.count('1CW')
```

simplest way to do this.